# Mongoose query using conditional formatting and regex

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I this the function createQuery is fully functionally, but I would like a review on it. I'm pretty sure this can be shorten and most important (improve performance). Any ideas?

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const CompanyPart = require("../models/parts");

router.post("/search", (req, res) => {
  function createQuery(bodyFieldName, mongodbFieldName) {
    if (bodyFieldName !== undefined && bodyFieldName !== "") {
      const trimmedString = bodyFieldName.trim();
      if (
        trimmedString.charAt(0) !== "*" &&
        trimmedString.charAt(trimmedString.length - 1) !== "*"
      ) {
        // screw
        return (query[mongodbFieldName] = new RegExp(
          "^" + trimmedString + "$",
          "i"
        ));
      } else if (
        trimmedString.charAt(0) === "*" &&
        trimmedString.charAt(trimmedString.length - 1) === "*"
      ) {
        // *screw*
        return (query[mongodbFieldName] = new RegExp(
          trimmedString.replace(/[*]/g, ""),
          "i"
        ));
      } else if (
        trimmedString.charAt(0) !== "*" &&
        trimmedString.charAt(trimmedString.length - 1) === "*"
      ) {
        // screw*
        return (query[mongodbFieldName] = new RegExp(
          "^" + trimmedString.replace(/[*]/g, ""),
          "i"
        ));
      } else if (
        trimmedString.charAt(0) === "*" &&
        trimmedString.charAt(trimmedString.length - 1) !== "*"
      ) {
        // *screw
        return (query[mongodbFieldName] = new RegExp(
          trimmedString.replace(/[*]/g, "") + "$",
          "i"
        ));
      }
    }
  }

  console.log("req.body", req.body);
  let query = {};

  createQuery(req.body.partNumber, "itemNumber");
  createQuery(req.body.partName, "partName");
  createQuery(req.body.customsTariff, "customsTariff");
  console.log("query", query);

  CompanyPart.find(query)
    .sort({
      itemNumber: 1
    })
    .exec((err, parts) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
        return;
      }
      res.status(200).json({ parts });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, using `new RegExp` on user input is a bit like running `eval` on user input (though not nearly as bad - usually). If it can be avoided, it should be. In this case, if I pass `.*?` as the `partName`, the regex will be `/^.*?$/i` which will match every entry in the database, or I could pass `(` which would result in the function throwing an error. This can be mitigated by escaping all special characters, but still isn't a good idea if there is another way to do this. (I haven't used MongoDB, but it appears the `$search` key might be useful - [MongoDB Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/).

---

If the built in `$search` parameter doesn't work for you, then the function should escape all special characters in the search string before creating a RegExp with it.

One way to do this is the following:

```js
function createRegex(userInput) {
  return new RegExp(
    // Escape all special characters except *
    "^" + userInput.replace(/([.+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1")
      // Allow the use of * as a wildcard like % in SQL.
      .replace(/\*/g, ".*") + "$",
    'i'
  );
}

['test', '*test*', '*test', 'test*', '[tes{2}t.'].forEach(test => {
  console.log(test, '=>', createRegex(test))
});
```

While this may be slightly slower than the current function, it is much safer and can greatly simplify the `createQuery` function. It also allows `createQuery` to cover the edge case where `*` appears in the middle of a string.

`createQuery` can now be implemented in only a few lines.

```js
function createQuery(userInput, dbField) {
  if (userInput === undefined) {
    return;
  }
  // Trim the input before checking as otherwise searching for a
  // single space could cause problems.
  userInput = userInput.trim();
  if (userInput !== "") {
    query[dbField] = createRegex(userInput);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, this could be shortened (at the cost of some readability) with

```js
function createQuery(userInput, dbField) {
  if (userInput && userInput = userInput.trim()) {
    query[dbField] = createRegex(userInput);
  }
}
```